# How do I persist the Network tab in safari develeper tools

Tags: safari, developer-tools

I am developing a web application and I have some actions that take place just before a refresh, one of which is an ajax call. I need to debug that call. Is there a way to persist the network log on page refresh in safari? Using Safari 10.0 if that helps.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494804/safari-developer-tools-preserve-network-log-on-navigation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safari Developer Tools: Preserve Network Log on Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494804/safari-developer-tools-preserve-network-log-on-navigation)