# Safari Developer Tools: Preserve Network Log on Navigation

Tags: debugging, safari, developer-tools, safari-web-inspector

When using [Safari Web Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to view the Network Log, the log is reset upon navigation, i.e. navigating to a different page clears the log.

In the [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#preserve-log), I can easily persist the network log by checking the "Preserve log" checkbox in the Network tab. In [Firefox Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor#Network_request_list), I can preserve the network log by checking "Enable persistent logs" in the developer tools preferences.

With this persistence enabled, the network log remains intact until I manually clear the output, simplifying the process of tracking requests and redirects that happen during navigation to a new page.

Is there a similar feature in Safari Web Inspector?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safari Developer Tools: How to Preserve Log Upon Navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572693/safari-developer-tools-how-to-preserve-log-upon-navigation)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In Safari 16.0 they have moved again:

[image: Safari network log settings]

---

In Safari 11.1.2 this is a setting on each tab under the checkbox "Preserve Log"

[image: Console tab]

[image: Network tab]

Note that if your Web Inspector window is too narrow to show all options, you'll have to expand it until it is wide enough to display the Preserve Log option, as mentioned in [an answer by ShortFuse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53215396/807834).

---

In Safari 11 this was in the Settings panel under "Network: Clear when page navigates", and it's sister setting "Console: Clear when page navigates".

[image: Safari settings for network and console clearing when page navigates]

Comment: You answered this a year ago already, and I'm using Safari 11.1.2, but I do not see these options. What version are you using and do you _still_ see these options there?

Comment: It looks like they moved it again! I've updated my post to show 11.1.2 placements as well.

Comment: Yup, the window being too small to show the options was my issue _facepalm_

Comment: I tried this setting on google.com to see the redirect path of an an ad. But the log is not preserved even though the setting is applied. Any idea?

Comment: It's been a while. But it seems to have moved again or maybe depending on resolution. For me it was under some weird circle-with-3-dashes icon.

Comment: Thanks for the updates to the updates!

Answer (score 19):

There is a `Preserve Log` option in `Network`.

The problem is that if your window is too narrow, it disappears and Safari gives you no indication that it's there. Resize your Web Inspector window to be wider.

(That was a fun one to figure out!)

Comment: This. Is. Gold :)

Answer (score 8):

This was *just* added to WebKit last week: https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/211451

You can expect it to make it into a Safari Technology Preview build soon. Once it's in a build, you can toggle preserving logs on navigation in the Settings Tab.

Comment: Any idea whether this setting is available somewhere in Safari 9.1.3? -- EDIT: Oops, I misread that your answer was from 2013. :)

Comment: @tuomassalo its a 2017 answer. 8th Feb 2017, 8:13pm :) And by the current version of safari 10.1.1, i can see network logs are preserved.

Comment: @DhairyaVora How to do you enable it?  I'm on Safari 10.1.1 and my network logs are cleared upon navigating to a new page.

Comment: @AndrewAllbright It's not in 10.1.2 as far as I can see, but it is in the "Technology Preview" version available here: https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/

Answer (score 0):

It is the logo with a circle and 3 horizontal lines that preserves network tab -> [preserve logs button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaQxl.png), at least in Version 16.0