# how to log http redirects when using Safari

Tags: http, safari, mobile-safari

Safari seems not to log http redirects in the network inspector tool.

I'm in a environment where I can't use http proxy (like Charles) so I'm wondering if there's any safari plugin able to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a bug in webkit:

[Web Inspector: Redirect requests are not shown in either Network or Timeline tabs](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=150005)

According to the page, the bug status is "NEW", so it's not fixed yet.

I've searched in Safari extension market but nothing is found.

I also find this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494804/safari-developer-tools-preserve-network-log-on-navigation) post and confirmed that in the latest Safari Technology Overview, Network requests info can be preserved when page navigates. However, redirect requests are not "preserved".