# How can you export a har file on Safari?

Tags: safari, safari-web-inspector

I have instructions to give to customers for how to send in har files for debugging SSO issues for all common browsers but Safari.  Remote debug is not an option.  My current instructions basically say "you can't do this on Safari"; I've seen others say this too.

I found this relatively recent stackoverflow post yesterday that says you can at least make the data persist now:

[Safari Developer Tools: Preserve Network Log on Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494804/safari-developer-tools-preserve-network-log-on-navigation/42122759)

So now I need to export it.  I found this link that gives some instructions, but at the last step, we don't see the 'copy all as HAR' selection.

http://help.catchsoftware.com/display/ET/Collecting+Browser+Performance+Information

Does anyone know how to export the browser network traffic on Safari?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13):

When you have the "Web inspector" visible in Safari and you're viewing the "Network" tab, the "Export" button at the top right will export a HAR file of the last loaded page.

Comment: One thing to note, when I try to do this using a `localhost` server, "Export" is greyed out most of the time so I can't actually download a HAR. Couldn't find any clues as to why this might be by some googling around. Safari version = 13.0.4, Mac version = 10.15.2.

Comment: Export not working for `localhost` in Safari 13.1.1 and Safari Technology Preview Release 109 (Safari 14.0) on macOS 10.15.5. Export is not greyed out, but clicking does not work.

Comment: If your `Export HAR` option is greyed out try refreshing the page with the Web Inspector open. If you open Web Inspector after the page loads you won't be able to `Export HAR`.

Comment: Where does it export to? The button is not grayed out, but when I click it, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can also right click on a single request and click save to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding that while *ay* request is incomplete it will not export!
Which makes it impossible to record/share failing requests.

(MacOS 14.1.2)